# android: produce json output from cakephp for login

Tags: php, android, json, cakephp-2.0

i'm new on android and i want create my app for my website programmed with cakePHP.

I create json output for some action for UsersController, but i don't know how generate json output for some action.

For example for list of users my index action it's so:

```
public function index() {
    $this->User->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
    $this->set('title_for_layout', __('Users'));
}
```

And create new file on subfolder /json/ so:

```
echo json_encode(Set::extract('/User/.', $users));
```

Now i want obtain the same result for login, but i don't know how do you do this.

My login action it's so:

```
function login() {
    if ($this->Auth->loggedIn())
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            // recupera il livello di privilegio
            $this->User->Group->id = $this->Auth->user('group_id');
            $this->Session->write(
                'Auth.User.level',
                $this->User->Group->field('level')
            );

            // salva accesso nella tabella loggers per tracciare gli accessi
            $this->loadModel('Logger');
            $data = array(
                'Logger' => array(
                    'id_user' => $this->Auth->user("id"),
                    'action_eng' => 'login',
                    'action_ita' => 'login',
                    'description_eng' => 'Logged in',
                    'description_ita' => 'Login eseguito',
                    'time_stamp' => date(DATE_ATOM)
                )
            );
            $this->Logger->create();
            $this->Logger->save($data);

            // salva ultimo accesso
            $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
            $this->User->saveField('last_login', date(DATE_ATOM), false);
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your username or password was incorrect.'));
        }
    }

    $this->set('data', $latest);
    $this->set('title_for_layout', __('Login'));
}
```

I must change this action?
What do you put on file login.ctp on json folder for encode json output for parsing on android app?

Thank you. CakePHP it's good, but documentations it's very poor!

Comment: Couldn't you just create another json folder in your UsersController views named login.ctp? Of course it depends on what you need... login involves setting a cookie so you might want that cookie to be handled in some way.

Comment: As I was saying, the only thing you have to output to the response is actually success or error status. The rest is handled with cookies.

Comment: so i create login.ctp with output json with success or error message?

Comment: Yes, but the rest must be handled with the cookie you'll receive from the response. Please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Comment: But this do not do the controller? On view login there isn't nothing for cookie.